# How Do I Add Add More Menus In A Context Menu?

Tags: excel, contextmenu, excel-2013, vba

I have made a context menu in Excel which works great. I am just unsure how to add another menu after `.Caption = "My Special Menu"`

So I would like the context menu to appear like this.

My Special Menu > IT > Microsoft Office (then the 2 buttons)

Is this possible in a context menu?

Also is it possible to have another menu under Microsoft Office when you press IT to say Google Docs with buttons in those also?

```
Option Explicit

Public Const Mname As String = "MyPopUpMenu"

Sub DeletePopUpMenu()
    ' Delete the popup menu if it already exists.
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(Mname).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub CreateDisplayPopUpMenu()
    ' Delete any existing popup menu.
    Call DeletePopUpMenu

    ' Create the popup menu.
    Call Custom_PopUpMenu_1

    ' Display the popup menu.
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(Mname).ShowPopup
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub Custom_PopUpMenu_1()
    Dim MenuItem As CommandBarPopup
    ' Add the popup menu.
    With Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=Mname, Position:=msoBarPopup, _
         MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)

        ' add a menu that contains two buttons.
        Set MenuItem = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
        With MenuItem
            .Caption = "My Special Menu"

            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                .Caption = "Button 1 in menu"
                .FaceId = 71
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & ""
            End With

            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                .Caption = "Button 2 in menu"
                .FaceId = 72
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "T"
            End With
        End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
       With MenuItem
        .Caption = "My Special Menu"
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=1)
            .Tag = "submenu1"
            .Caption = "IT"
            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=1)
                .Tag = "Submenu2"
                .Caption = "Microsoft Office!"


                With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=1)
                        .Tag = "btn1"
                        .Caption = "Button 1 in menu"
                        .FaceId = 71
                        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & ""
                End With
                With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                        .Tag = "btn2"
                        .Caption = "Button 2 in menu"
                        .FaceId = 72
                        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "T"
                End With

            End With
        End With
      End With
```